# ELDA - Linked Data API, define sorting option

Tags: java, sorting, sparql, linked-data

I have the endpoint which lists all games which include {name} parameter and what I want to implement currently is to give user an option of choosing the ordering of the results.

```
games?name={game}
```

Something similar as:

```
games?name={game}&order={order}
```

you can see the partial implementation of my endpoint. Currently api:orderBy is statically written.

```
api:selector [
    api:where " ?item a epic:Game . ?item epic:Name ?name . FILTER (regex(?name, ?game, 'i')) " ;
    api:orderBy "DESC(?name)"
]
.
```

I am using ELDA.

Comment: See the  [Elda cribsheet](http://epimorphics.github.io/elda/current/cribsheet.html) either _sort or _orderBy parameters look like they might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @chrisis Not actually what i was looking for but yeah I ended up using them